# How to root Samsung S4 SGH-M919V

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Title. It has 4.2.2 android

Does the method for the sgh-m919 works?

It's not a duplicated question, I checked. Thanks everyone

Comment: Welcome to AE stack exchange! While I cripple over a bricked phone, try checking the rooting tag-wiki (tap the rooting tag, then learn more in the box near the top) In the meantime, look around, andnsee if you can answer anything!

Comment: The sane method would be to get a custom recovery and flash SuperSU, but how to get a custom recovery may depend of the specific device.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to get root on your device is called CF-Auto-root.

Follow these steps:

- Flash the CF-Auto-Root package as PDA in ODIN, and your device should reboot into a modified recovery (signified by a large red Android logo) and it will install SuperSU for you and restore the stock recovery, and reboot back into Android.
- If you don't get to the red Android logo, boot into recovery manually (`adb reboot recovery`, or boot while holding Power+VolUp+Home).
- Using this root increases your flash counter. You should run Triangle Away after rooting to reset the counter. Note that if you want to run custom kernels or custom recoveries, your flash counter will be set to 1 at every boot. Either configure Triangle Away to reset the counter at every boot (Play version only) or only reset the counter when you need to go into warranty.
- Did you see the red Android logo during rooting, but SuperSU does not appear? This may sometimes occur due to left-over files and settings, however, you can usually install SuperSU from Google Play at this stage and it'll just work.

Detailed ODIN steps:

- Download and unzip the CF-Auto-Root.zip file for your model (eg.: [SGH-M919](https://download.chainfire.eu/328/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-jfltetmo-jfltetmo-sghm919.zip))
- If you end up with a recovery.img and cache.img file, you've extracted twice. You need to end up with a .tar.md5 file - don't extract that one
- (USB) Disconnect your phone from your computer
- Start Odin3-vX.X.exe
- Click the PDA button, and select CF-Auto-Root.tar.md5
- Put your phone in download mode (turn off phone, then hold VolDown+Home+Power to boot - if it asks you to press a button to continue, press the listed button, or run adb reboot download command)
- (USB) Connect the phone to your computer
- Make sure Repartition is NOT checked
- Click the Start button
- Wait for Android to boot
- Done (if it took you more than 30 seconds, you need practise!)

**NOTE**: Sometimes the device does *not* boot into recovery mode and root your device. Just do the entire procedure again if this happens. If it still will not install root and such, make sure that in Odin "Auto Reboot" is not checked. Then after flashing, pull the battery, and boot with VolUp+Home+Power button to boot into recovery manually. This will start the install process.

You may now optionally want to install and run `Triangle Away` to reset the flash counter.

If you have SIM locked device (AT&T, VZW, etc) do not use this method due to its locked Bootloader.

If your device Bootloader is locked do not use this method.

*Disclaimer:
I am not responsible for any kind of damage you do to your android device
(This doesnt really mean you will damage your android device, theres a really rare chance something bad happens, but thats only if you do something wrong)*

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2294005)